# Use silverlight to query mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, silverlight

I have a silverlight application which reads data from a db and displays them in a grid.
As far as i understand it there are two ways to do it.
1) Read db with a server-side language, such as php, create a file in the server which you can later use in Silverlight to read the data.
2) Connect "directly" using Silverlight code with your db and do your job there. I have read some posts that explain more or less how this is possible, but i haven't found a working example.

I really need to go towards the 2nd approach. Can anyone provide a simple example on how to connect and query to your mysql db safely from Silverlight?

Thank you.

Comment: It is important to note that anything that connects directly to the database will end up needing a password in some way (either stored in the application or input by the user).  If you store it in the application then it will be easy for almost anybody to rip it out.

Comment: so what would you suggest?
another way would be to use method1. Create a local file in the server, read it and then delete it. But how can you tell from silverlight that you need to delete this file?

Comment: @david - if you create a registered account (which is free etc) you won't accidentally create duplicate accounts. I've merged the previous two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [MySQL connector for Entity Framework](http://hypertrends.com/Blog/post/2009/03/17/MySQL-with-Entity-Framework-in-NET35.aspx) and then connect to the database using [.NET RIA Services](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/RiaServices).

Whatever route you go you're going to need to create some method to read data from the database on the server and return that to Silverlight as objects.

Comment: house-keeping; the OP left a comment-as-an-answer (now deleted): "bryant, is there a sample somewhere on this?"

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight runs on the client side in the browser, there is no way to directly hit a database.  The way to get data is to hit a webservice, you could use ADO Data Services but they only run Sql Server in their cloud.